# Why is probability density function is always positive?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I saw that one of the properties of probability density function is that it is always positive.

But I am not sure how to prove that?

Comment: Small modification: it is non-negative, not necessarily positive.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By definition the probability density function is the derivative of the distribution function. But distribution function is an increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$ thus  its derivative is always positive.

Comment: Not quite. Distribution functions are nondecreasing functions, not increasing functions, and their derivatives are always nonnegative, not always positive.  See the comment by Andre on the main question.

Comment: yes, of cource, thanks for the refinement

Comment: very great interpretation

Comment: a pdf is not necessary the derivative of the cdf at all points. See chapter 1 in "Statistical Inference"

Answer (score 3):

Assume that probability density of X is -ve in the interval (a, b). Now, let us define an event A such X lies between a and b. This is nothing but integral of density between a and b. Thus, P(a < X < b) < 0. But by definition, probability can never be negative. Thus, density can never be negative.